# pywinauto не корректно работает в режиме многопоточности

Tags: python, pywinauto

**Expected Behavior**

COM работают в отдельных потоках, в режиме многопоточности и не должны блокировать друг друга.

**Actual Behavior**

COM работают в отдельных потоках, в режиме многопоточности, но при этом, при блокировке одного из приложений, в хаотичном порядке блокируется второе приложение (на разных участках кода, до куда успеет дойти).

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem**

- Из под разных корутин (asyncio) создается свой инстанс с Application(backend='UIA').connect(process=...)
- Далее, каждая корутина поочередно запускает приложение 1С (авторизуется - Application(backend='UIA').start("...")), идет на создание и выгрузку отчета в 1С через GUI (pywinauto).
- После нажатия на кнопку, блокирующую открытое окно сессии (приложения), передаю управление на другую корутину. Тут ожидаю выполнения посредством wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.2). Пока отчет выгружается, threshold находится в районе 7%.
- На другой корутине, при блокировке предыдущей, python может встать в ожидание на любом участке кода pywinauto (хаотично), connect успевает выполниться корректно, top_window, set_focus, уже не всегда успевает. Далее методы pywinauto (window, descendants и т.п.) уже блокируются (очень часто, но тоже **НЕ ВСЕГДА**), пока не разблокируется приложение в первой корутине.
- TID приложения во всех запущенных сессиях 1С одинаковый (win32api.GetCurrentThreadId).
  А вот PID и TID (win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId) окон разные.
- Сценарий, в данном случае, запускаю одинаковый, на одних и тех же данных.

**Specifications**

- Pywinauto version: 0.6.4, т.к. только на ней 1С может работать в многопоточном режиме более-менее корректно.
- Python version and bitness: python 3.7, 64x.
- Platform and OS: приложение 1С Предприятие на Windows Server 2016 64x.

Comment: Можно попробовать выставить `sys.coinit_flags = 2` перед `import pywinauto`. Это COM threading режимы STA или MTA: 0 по умолчанию или 2 можно выставить.

Comment: Пробовал флаги. с 2 вообще не работает. мультипоток это же 0? На 0 сидит версия 0.6.4 по умолчанию.

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov, еще уточнение - TID приложения во всех запущенных сессиях 1С одинаковый (win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()). А вот PID и TID (win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId) окон разные.

Comment: Вот например сейчас:
В то время, как первое приложение не отвечает (грузит очет) wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.2, timeout=1000), второе: 
 * успешно открылось Application(backend='UIA).start('строка запуска exe...')
 * далее, выполняется успешно app = Application(backend='UIA).connect(process='...')
 * успешно цепляется окно wnd = app.window(control_type='Window', found_index=0). Если top_window() - тут больше вероятности что застрянет.
 * успешно получает wnd.legacy_properties()['Name']
 * получает wnd.descendants(title='Панель окон', control_type='ToolBar').button_count()

Comment: * получает wnd.children, wnd.child_window
 * close() дочерних окон отрабатывает
 * на wnd.maximize() ВСТАЛ. Это только при этом запуске. Повторно, может и дальше пройти. С чем связано не понимаю...

Comment: Ну, вообще `.top_window()` вносит значительную рандомность, поэтому её не рекомендуется использовать, и вот почему: это создаётся спецификация окна в духе .window(handle=current_hwnd), но `current_hwnd` берётся в момент вызова top_window(), а если окна новые создаются. то момент этот непредсказуем. Но запоминается часто старое окно, и это вносит много непонимания. Разные окна (от разных экземпляров 1С), очевидно, находятся в разных процессах. То, что номер потока совпал - это чистая случайность. Поток - он внутри процесса.

Comment: Вообще, можем встретиться офлайн и вместе дебажнуться) Телега: vasily_v_ryabov Потом тут отпостим решение.

Comment: Согласен, отписался.